# Web Api returning undesired format of json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

**Method:**

```
[Route("api/vms/getpowerstatus/{vmsid}")]
[HttpGet]
public string getpowerstatus(string vmsid)
{ 
    Result rs = new Result();
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        String timeStamp = GetTimestamp();

        string q = "select vmsid, vmspowerstatus ,vmspowerdatetime from public.vmssnapshot  ";
        ds = vm.GetVMS(q);
        rs.vmsid = vmsid;
        rs.status = "success";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( ds.Tables[0] , Formatting.None);
        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    } 
}
```

**Response:**

```
"[{\"vmsid\":\"512\",\"vmspowerstatus\":null,\"vmspowerdatetime\":null},{\"vmsid\":\"VMSBhandup98\",\"vmspowerstatus\":null,\"vmspowerdatetime\":null},{\"vmsid\":\"tquwuer\",\"vmspowerstatus\":null,\"vmspowerdatetime\":null},{\"vmsid\":\"VMSBlock\",\"vmspowerstatus\":\"1\",\"vmspowerdatetime\":1539022768},{\"vmsid\":\"uu4443\",\"vmspowerstatus\":\"1\",\"vmspowerdatetime\":1534917021},{\"vmsid\":\"cms_bhandup\",\"vmspowerstatus\":\"1\",\"vmspowerdatetime\":1539022544},{\"vmsid\":\"vmsBolakk\",\"vmspowerstatus\":\"1\",\"vmspowerdatetime\":1539631400}]"
```

**Desired response:**

```json
[{vmsid:'512',vmspowerstatus:'test'.....}]
```

Comment: What happens if you use the default serilizer by just returning ds.Tables[0] form the method?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund then i would have to change the return type of method to `Datatable` but i am not always returning DataTable. for eg; In catch i am returning an object with two properties ID and MSG

Comment: U could just try with return type IHttpActionResult, then do "return Ok(ds.Tables[0]);"

Comment: Your desired response is invalid json format. Response is actually desired format.

Comment: I know. But our client is having some issue in node js. After parsing the string he is unable to access the properties  : parsedvariable[0] // gives him "["

Comment: Where do you see that response? If you are checking it using visual studio, it might "escape" you string should that "response" but at the end, it is, in fact, your "desired response".

Comment: So there is a problem on clients side. What you  are going to do if you have 2 clients accessing same API? change data format per client? That's nonsense. So it's clients problem to deal with totally valid json

Comment: @Reniuz lol tell me about it.

Comment: Your question is misleading - api returns desired json but you need a custom format result. You need to write custom serializer or some sort of transformation. Now have you tried to do that? Where was a problem?

Comment: @Reniuz usually there is no "\" before every column in json.

Comment: Dump string to file and you will see - there is no. It's [escape sequence for double quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). Debugger shows them. Try to write same string in code without \ and you will see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

[Asp.Net web api serialize your result in json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), so you don't need to serialize yourself the result. Just return the object or enumerable of objects to serialize.

If you need custom serialization, you can configure the serializer in the registration of web api configuration

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    //configure serializer
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'";
}
```